# Data of previous user is displayed after another user is signed in

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Update**

I had every activity set as SingleInstance on launch mode, which makes sense why the issue had appear. Set it as default or SingleTop and it clears out the issue.

So, I'm making an android app where there is Firebase email auth for signing in and out. There is a ProfileActivity that shows user's profile picture and other information like images, posts and etc. When that user is signed out, and another user is logged in and navigates to profileActivity, the data from the previous user appears. But if the app is closed and restarted, then everything is fine, the correct data is displayed. This sigin and signout are done simultaneously without closing the app and only then the problem seems to appear.

I've tried modifying rules in the firebase database, rechecked the signout method and didn't find any related issue.

### Firebase database rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

### sign out method

```
auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
auth.signOut();
```

### these methods are included too

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    auth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);

}

@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    if(authStateListener != null){
        auth.removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: ..and no crash?

Comment: No, it doesn't crash.

Comment: This is not a solution, it's just a tip. Check if `auth.getCurrentUser() == null` after you sign out and again before you sign in. Also (and more importantly), how are you getting the user data? Directly from Firebase or through an intermediary db?

Comment: I've those methods where it checks auth.getCurrentUser() == null after I signout and sigin. I'm using intermediary db to get the data from firebase.

Comment: I think I know what's wrong now. You're getting the user details with `UserProfileChangeRequest ` right?

Comment: If you actually used `UserProfileChangeRequest `, a delayed data-update is not unusual, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42330460/5670752).

Comment: @TaslimOseni I'm not using 'UserProfileChangeRequest' to get the user details, but I had every activity launched as SingleInstance and removing it fixed it which makes sense. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Awesome! You can add an explanation on how you fixed the issue (as an answer) to help others that might have the same problem.